# Why is show helper not leading to show.html.erb but to index.html.erb?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Here's my code that's causing trouble:

```rb
  <% @user.goals.each do |goal| %>
    <tr>
      <td><%= link_to goal.text, user_goals_path(@user, goal)%></td>
    </tr>
  <% end %>
```

I thought user_goals_path(@user, @goal) was correct, but apparently it keeps going to index.html.erb.

My show and index in the controller:

```rb
    def index
        @user = User.find(params[:user_id])
        @goal = @user.goals
    end

    def show
        @user = User.find(params[:user_id])
        @goal = @user.goals.find(params[:id])
    end
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

UPDATE:

Thank you for the comments. Here's my route:

```
               user_goals GET    /user/:user_id/goals(.:format)                                                           goals#index
                          POST   /user/:user_id/goals(.:format)                                                           goals#create
            new_user_goal GET    /user/:user_id/goals/new(.:format)                                                       goals#new
           edit_user_goal GET    /user/:user_id/goals/:id/edit(.:format)                                                  goals#edit
                user_goal GET    /user/:user_id/goals/:id(.:format)                                                       goals#show
                          PATCH  /user/:user_id/goals/:id(.:format)                                                       goals#update
                          PUT    /user/:user_id/goals/:id(.:format)                                                       goals#update
                          DELETE /user/:user_id/goals/:id(.:format)                                                       goals#destroy
```

And route.rb:

```rb
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  devise_for :users

  resources :user do
    resources :goals
  end

  devise_scope :user do
    authenticated :user do
      root 'home#index', as: :authenticated_root
    end

    unauthenticated do
      root 'devise/sessions#new', as: :unauthenticated_root
    end
  end
end
```

As mentioned in the comment, user_goal_path(@user, goal) generates an error in the goal list:

```
No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"goals", :id=>nil, :user_id=>"1"}, missing required keys: [:id]
```

UPDATE 2:

Could this be the problem? Here's my schema. Do you see anything wrong here, per my goal to show goal?

```
  create_table "goals", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.text "text"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.bigint "user_id"
    t.index ["user_id"], name: "index_goals_on_user_id"
  end
```

Comment: have you tried `./bin/rails routes` to list out all available routes and see if `user_goals_path` is pointing to `users#show`?

Comment: @LucasK Thank you. Yes, it actually says user_goal for showing the goal. But, weirdly, user_goal_path(@user, @goal) will generate an error for displaying the goal list. The error message: ```No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"goals", :id=>nil, :user_id=>"1"}, missing required keys: [:id]
``` So I can't even get to check whether this would work.

Comment: @thebot Can you show the output of the route on the terminal by running the command `rake routes | grep goals` ?

Comment: Can you also post the `routes.rb` to better understand how you define the routes?

Comment: @LucasK Thank you, posted!

Comment: @Gabbar Thank you, posted!

Comment: @thebot You've a typo. `user_goals_path` should be `user_goal_path` if you want it to direct to the show.

Comment: You might also want to use [shallow nesting](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#shallow-nesting), since the Rails Routing guide specifically says *"Resources should never be nested more than 1 level deep."* in [the Nested Resources section](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#nested-resources).

Answer (score 0):

`user_goals_path(@user, goal)` seems like an auto-generated route to an :index action.

If it was to a :show action it probably would have been `user_goal_path(@user, goal)` instead, to show an user goal.

Like Lucas K said, posting your `rake routes` output can help with further diagnose.

Answer (score 0):

For this routes it requires only `user_id` parameter pass dynamically

```
           user_goals GET    /user/:user_id/goals(.:format)     goals#index
```

So it would be

```
<td><%= link_to goal.text, user_goals_path(@user)%></td>
<td><%#= link_to goal.text, user_goals_path(@current_user)%></td>
```

For routes, it requires `user_id` and `id` parameter pass dynamically

```
            user_goal GET    /user/:user_id/goals/:id(.:format)     goals#show
```

So It would be

```
<td><%= link_to goal.text, user_goal_path(@user, @goal)%></td>
<td><%#= link_to goal.text, user_goal_path(@current_user, @goal)%></td>
```

Comment: Thank you. This doesn't seem to work. But do you think the problem might be what I posted in the bottom of my post ("UPDATE 2")?

Answer (score 0):

After I tried shallow nested resources, I could move from the list to the show page with this:

```rb
  <% @user.goals.each do |goal| %>
    <tr>
      <td><%= link_to goal.text, goal_path(@user,goal)%></td>
    </tr>
  <% end %>
```